# Help on getting data to output when a variable changes

Tags: javascript, json, mootools

I am trying to write a JavaScript interface for an Api, but I can not figure out this issue. I have code to call an ajax request:

```
    mooshark.request('userInfoFromID', {
        userID : '20991'
    });
```

That code creates an Ajax request. When it starts, it sets an internal variable to true (to indicate that it is running). Then on the next line I have this:

```
    var data = mooshark.response();
    alert(data);
```

The response function is as follows:

```
    response: function () {
        if(this.running == false){
            return "done";
        } else if (this.running == true){
            alert("Running");
            setTimeout(this.response, 3000);
        }
    }
```

It outputs (in this order) Running. undefined. (JSON response). Running. Not once does it output "done". Is there a way to return "done" when this.running becomes true? I would like to mention that this.running will not always be the same request time. I know there is always the option of wrapping all my code inside the onCompleat function in the ajax request, but I want to have that as a last resort.

Thanks!

Comment: pass on `async: false` to the request object. it's crap as it freezes the UI thread and waits for the response but it may work better than the setTimeout way and it will return the data once it's received it. i don't understand why you'd consider the `onComplete` as a last resort, it is how ajax works... also, if your class extends `Request`, having `this.response` will conflict with the native object that mootools uses to store the response object of the XHR (eg, in onComplete you can query `this.response.text` etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without freezing the browser.

Whenever your code is running, the browser UI will be completely frozen.
If you want the call to wait for the server to reply, the browser will need to be competely frozen.  (which is not a good idea)

Comment: Thanks. Guess, I have to try a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the time you're calling response() through setTimeout(), a return value isn't really useful.

But -- you're likely never setting your 'running' variable to false. You might post more code here (the AJAX response handling code, for example). Also: what exactly are you trying to accomplish by returning / alerting "running" and "done"?